# Winforms приложение, которое не завершается если закрыть стартовую форму

Tags: c#, winforms

**Есть две формы:** родительская и дочерняя.

При нажатии определенного `button` на родительской форме, родительская скрывается, а дочерняя показывается. А можно каким-либо образом не скрывать, а полностью закрыть родительскую, но сохранить дочернюю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, что вы скрываете за словами "родительска" и "дочерняя". Если одна форма содержит код, отображающий другую форму, то это не делает первую "родительской". Просто отображайте вторую форму не указывая первую в качестве "родительской". Смотрите тут: [Form.Show Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вызывая метод `Form.Show()` без параметра `ownerWindow` можно отображать форму, не указывая "владельца".

Другое дело, если первая форма является "главной" формой приложения, т.е. приложение сделано так, что его жизненный цикл связан с первой формой. В таком случае, закрытие первой формы приведёт к завершению работы приложения. Чтобы этого не происходило, надо просто...воспользоваться поисковиком.

Смотрите, какая удачная статья в MSDN: [Application.Run - метод (ApplicationContext)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms157901.aspx)

Всё, что вам нужно, это объявить класс, управляющий жизненным циклом приложения, наследник от `ApplicationContext` и запустить своё приложение с этим контекстом.

```
class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext 
{
    private MyApplicationContext() 
    {
        form1 = new AppForm1();
        form1.Show();
    }
}    

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        //Запускаем приложение со своим контекстом. 
        //Он не будет завершать приложение без вашего желания.
        MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();
        Application.Run(context);
    }
}
```

Теперь приложение не будет само завершать работу, только по вашей команде, даже если закрыть все формы.

---

Вам осталось решить, как вы будете закрывать приложение. Например, можно:

```
    //Реагируем на закрытие одной из форм.
    private void OnFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //Когда вы решите, что приложению пора закрываться, вызывайте:
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Можно сделать проще - `Application.Run()` ведь можно и без параметров вызывать.